# $.get appending current url to request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to do a ajax call using `$.get` like so:

```
jQuery.get('www.example.com/some-url?q=node/09090&dest=example', function(result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```

Please note the url is an empty string. Even though I've purposely left it empty, when I check the request is being made to the current `url` that originates the request (where my js sits).

For clarity, let's say my js is within a page viewable on this address: `www.example.com/my-page`, with the above code, even though I've left the `url` string empty, on Firebug console I can see a request is being made to `www.example.com/my-page`. Why is that? And most importantly, how I can get rid of this behaviour?

Please note that if I add anything to the url string like so:

```
jQuery.get('myfile.php', function(result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```

The request is made to `www.example.com/my-pagemyfile.php`, meaning that it appends to whatever I use on the url string.

Note: For reasons beyond the scope of the question, the js in inline. Here's some of my code:

```
MktoForms2.loadForm("someaddress.com", "98978782", 1273, function (form) {
    var data = modal.find('.downloadResource');
    ...
    jQuery.ajax({url: "", cache: false, success: function (result) {
       console.log(result);
    }});
}});
```

Please ignore some of the pseudo code above. This code sits within a Drupal page. And it has to inline

Comment: More importantly, where are you expecting a request with no URL specified to actually be sent to?

Comment: if that was directed to me, I didn't downvote you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a normal behavior to make the call to the current url if you don't add anything. Of course if you add something.php, it will be the current URL + something.php. If you add /something.php it will be current domain + something.php. What is the full URL that you want? Maybe this way we can figure out what's your real "issue".

Based on your comment, you should have:

```
jQuery.ajax({url: "/?q=something", cache: false, success: function (result) {
    console.log(result);
}});
```

Comment: Ok, how can I use a completely different url (though the same domain?). For instance, let's say the current url is `www.example.com/my-file` and I want the request to `www.example.com/?q=node/10090&dest=somethingelse`

Comment: just do '/?q=node/10090&dest=somethingelse'

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to request `www.example.com/my-file.php` instead? Then can't you do:

```
jQuery.get('/myfile.php', function(result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```